# sending Tr064 Requests to AVM FritzBox 7270

Tags: c#, soap, upnp, fritzbox

I am just learning how to send SOAP requests to my AVM FritzBox 7270 router using C#.

Here ist my method that sends a SOAP request to the router:

```
    private string Execute(string controlUrl, string serviceType, string action)
    {
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://fritz.box:49000" + controlUrl);
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest;
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPACTION", string.Format("{0}#{1}", serviceType, action));
        httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        httpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 
        Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();

        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.ASCII);

        streamWriter.Write(GetBody(serviceType, action));
        streamWriter.Close();
        //Get the Response    
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse wr = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader srd = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream());
            return srd.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Function GetBody:

```
    private string GetBody(string serviceType, string action)
    {
        const string fmt = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" s:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"">
  <s:Body>
    <u:{0} xmlns:u=""{1}"" />
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
";        
            return string.Format(fmt, action, serviceType);
        }
    }
```

I tested this method with parameters that I found anywhere in the internet:

```
controlUrl = "/upnp/control/WANIPConn1"
serviceType = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1"
action = "GetExternalIPAddress"
```

This works well.

However, I think I should go the official way and first send a request

```
http://fritz.box:49000/tr64desc.xml
```

to receive parameters valid for my actual router. In the response to this request I find the following node:

```
<service>
  <serviceType>urn:dslforum-org:service:WANIPConnection:1</serviceType>
  <serviceId>urn:WANIPConnection-com:serviceId:WANIPConnection1</serviceId>
  <controlURL>/upnp/control/wanipconnection1</controlURL>
  <eventSubURL>/upnp/control/wanipconnection1</eventSubURL>
  <SCPDURL>/wanipconnSCPD.xml</SCPDURL>
</service>
```

Using these values for serviceId and controlUrl, I get error 500 (Internal Server Error).

Who can help me? What is wrong in my code?

Comment: That could be a bug in the device ... but how do you know http://fritz.box:49000/tr64desc.xml is the service description you should use? Are you actually getting that from SSDP discovery?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is solved:

There seem to be a lot of undocumeted features of the Fritz.Box, and the pararmeters I found in the internet oviously are part of thease features.

With

```
<service>
  <serviceType>urn:dslforum-org:service:WANPPPConnection:1</serviceType>
  <serviceId>urn:WANPPPConnection-com:serviceId:WANPPPConnection1</serviceId>
  <controlURL>/upnp/control/wanpppconn1</controlURL>
  <eventSubURL>/upnp/control/wanpppconn1</eventSubURL>
  <SCPDURL>/wanpppconnSCPD.xml</SCPDURL>
</service>
```

I can call

```
GetExternalIPAddress
```

without problems.